# jQuery / CSS navigation, cant get the "fnutt" to the center

Tags: jquery, css

I cant fix this little CSS/jQuery problem.

I want the "fnutt" under the menu to be in the center of each `<li></li>`
I guess you will understand what i mean if you take a look at my jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/pJjRg/

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: try using `position:relative;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the following changes:

```
#menu ul li  { 
    position: relative;
    ...
}

.triangle {
    ...
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:-7px; 
    left:50%; 
    margin-left: -8px
}
```

By setting `position: relative` on the parent `li` elements, the absolutely positioned `.triangles` are now positioned relative to the `li`s.  Then it is just a matter of positioning them with `bottom` `left` and `margin`.

http://jsfiddle.net/pJjRg/21/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the position of triangle as it varies for every menu item. Your JS code is ok.

Comment: So i cant get it dynamic? 
I want it to work by just adding a new list-item.. :/